# Use Cases of Otway Rees key exchange protocol

Tags: security, encryption, web, cryptography, public-key-exchange

I am working on an seminar paper regarding key exchange protocols. Of course my first choice of protocol was DH. Second, I choose Otway Rees protocol since I found it very interesting that there is not much literature existing.

So I did a little bit of research and have some basic knowledge regarding OR-protocol. I thing I somehow couldn't find were applications / use cases of Utway-Rees.

In literature they are talking about that its used for parties to agree on a secret key using TTP in unsafe networks and that its a common thing for VPNs. But one thing I am still missing is: where is implemented? Does it have some applications in TLS/SSL, or IPSec?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question.

Comment: I agree with you James. that this is not a programming question. I'm just curious whether this protocol is implemented somewhere so I can dig deeper. I would be very happy if I could get at least one productive answer from somebody who is familiar with this protocol.

Comment: Maybe this rather belongs to https://crypto.stackexchange.com?